# How to create multiple collection instances using requirejs and backbone

Tags: backbone.js, collections, requirejs

I am trying to create some common modules so that it can be reused on multiple Backbone.Collection, but I am stuck with the following problem.

I have downloaded https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate to be my application template, so in /app/modules, I have created the following js

- /app/modules/collection.js (Common stuff for all other collections)
- /app/modules/users.js (User Collection which extend from collection.js)

In /app/modules/collection.js the codes are:

```
define([
  "backbone"
],

function(Backbone) {

    var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        pagination : { total : 0 },

        parse: function( response ) {

            if ( response.data ) {
                self.pagination.total = response.total;
                return response.data;
            } 

            return response;
        },

    });

    return collection;

});
```

In /app/modules/users.js the codes are:

```
define([
  "backbone",
  "modules/collection"
],

function(Backbone, Collection) {

    var users = Collection.extend({
        self: null,

        initialize: function( models, options ) {
            self = this;
        },

        getData: function() {
            this.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log('ok');
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return users;

});
```

In my /app/router.js the codes are:

```
define([
  "app",
  "modules/users"
],

function(app, Users) {

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        var usersA = new Users([], {
          url: 'http://test.test.test./users_a.html'
        });
        usersA.getData();

        var usersB = new Users([], {
            url: 'http://dev.digbil.com/users_b.html'
        });    
        usersB.getData();
     }
  });

  return Router;

});
```

http://test.test.test./users_a.html suppose to return 20 records, so in usersA.pagination.total it should contain the value 20

http://test.test.test./users_b.html suppose to return 50 records, so in usersA.pagination.total it should contain the value 50

My problem is that both usersA.pagination.total contain the value 50, it seems like the second instance is overwriting the first instance?

But both userA.models, and userB.models contain correct data records, where it shows 20 users in my usersA collection, and 50 users in my userB collection.

If I execute them separately like:

```
define([
  "app",
  "modules/users"
],

function(app, Users) {

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        var usersA = new Users([], {
          url: 'http://test.test.test./users_a.html'
        });
        usersA.getData();
     }
  });

  return Router;

});
```

userA.pagination.total contain the correct value 20

```
define([
  "app",
  "modules/users"
],

function(app, Users) {

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        var usersB = new Users([], {
            url: 'http://dev.digbil.com/users_b.html'
        });    
        usersB.getData();
    }
  });

  return Router;

});
```

userB.pagination.total contain the correct value 50

Not sure where I am doing it wrong?

[Edit]  How should I change my codes to have different pagination values for each unique instance?

[Edit]  http://jsfiddle.net/mcchin/Bb5sq/ Quick mockup

[Edit]  It seems like problem is in "parse" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common behaviour of javascript object. Here you have to set in each collection initial pagination value `pagination : { total : 0 }`.

When you extend your collection it creates not a copy but a reference to the `pagination` value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb5sq/12

Comment: How should I change my codes to have different pagination values for each unique instance?

Comment: I have actually tried the version in your answer, I get the same results (pagination defined in users.js, or collection.js, or in both users.js and collection.js). I have also tried not to predefined pagination but only create it in users.initalize function and after running getData for both instances the first instance pagination.total is always the default value 0.

Comment: The problem is similar, the first instance will have pagination.total still equal to zero..I will try to put up codes in jsfiddler

Comment: Even if it works, it probably will defeat the purpose of having a reusable collection.js..

Comment: @forestclown add `this.pagination = {total: 0};` in the `initialize` method of your collection (easiest solution). Another solution would be to change `defaults` into a function that would return your `defaults` set. Another solution would be to create a new object each time you change `pagination`: `(this.pagination = _.clone(this.pagination).total = response.total;`.

Comment: @Loamhoof I tried that before as well, but it doesn't work, even in http://jsfiddle.net/mcchin/Bb5sq, when I passed in testA, and testB via initialization, both instances ends up having testB...